# Passing string to function

Tags: string, pointers

I have string which I want to pass to a function to be filled with data however it's not working for me. When I try and printf the string either in the function or after the function call it doesn't display anything and just exits. Any advice much appreciated.

```
int main(){

    char *myString = calloc(8, sizeof(char));
    change_string(&myString);
    printf("%s\n", myString);

    return 0;
}

int change_string(char **s){
    int bytes = 8;
    int err;
    err=function_to_hardware_device(*myString, 8);

    return err;
}
```

Comment: `change_string(myString); int change_string(char *s){ err=function_to_hardware_device(myString, 8); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed code

`change_string(myString);`

`int change_string(char *s)`

`err=function_to_hardware_device(myString, 8);`

By using `&myString` you were sending the pointer of the string, but in function you were taking a pointer to pointer of string.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Much appreciated. I spent 2 hours on this and was contemplating throwing the computer :D